# Error when retrieving values from MS SQL using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, entity

I've done a program where I have to retrieve the data from a table in MS SQL. I'm using `Hibernate` where `AbtDebtbyCAN` is an `Entity` class. The connection so far is fine but the only problem I'm facing is printing out data from MS SQL using Annotation Mapping. `Debt` is the name of the table(the name of the table is in lower case) which is to be mapped with. Below here is the result I want to print it out using `Hibernate`. Can anybody help me on how to achieve the fetching of data?

**debt**

```
  id          can           bdrl_debt    excess_ta_debt      posting_ref   debt_settlement_id   debt_settlement_at       debt_business_date
  
11425   1099112400000003        0              200             501728             137        2020-10-13 10:51:50.000         2020-10-13
```

**AbtDebtbyCAN**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "debt")
public class AbtDebtbbyCAN implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int debt_id;

@Column(name = "can")
private int debt_can;

@Column(name = "bdrl_debt")
private int bdrl_debt;

@Column(name = "excess_ta_debt")
private int excess_ta_debt;

@Column(name = "posting_ref")
private int posting_ref;

@Column(name = "debt_settlement_id")
private int debt_settlement_id;

@Column(name = "debt_settlement_at")
private DateTime debt_settlement_at;

@Column(name = "debt_business_date")
private Date debt_business_date;

}
```

**AbtCANMapperTest**

```
public class AbtCANMapperTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
    Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();

    SessionFactory factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();




        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            List abtdebt = session.createQuery("FROM AbtDebtbbyCAN WHERE debt_can=1099112400000003").getResultList();
            for (Iterator iterator = abtdebt.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                AbtDebtbbyCAN abtcan = (AbtDebtbbyCAN) iterator.next();
                System.out.print("debt id: " + abtcan.getDebt_id());
                System.out.print("debt can: " + abtcan.getDebt_can());
                System.out.print("bdrl debt: " + abtcan.getBdrl_debt());
                System.out.print("excess debt: " + abtcan.getExcess_ta_debt());
                System.out.print("posting ref: " + abtcan.getPosting_ref());
                System.out.print("debt settlement id: " + abtcan.getDebt_settlement_id());
                System.out.print("debt settlement at: " + abtcan.getDebt_settlement_at());
                System.out.println("debt business date: " + abtcan.getDebt_business_date());
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }


}
}
```

**Error StackTrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1542)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at AbtMainTestControl.AbtTestObj.AbtCANMapperTest.main(AbtCANMapperTest.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3088)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:995)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1415)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000AC53
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:899)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize


> Task :AbtCANMapperTest.main() FAILED

Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000AC53

Execution failed for task ':AbtCANMapperTest.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Can anybody tell me what's the issue? I'm desperate for an answer

Comment: Will a `can` value of 16 digits actually deserialize into a Java `int`? Maybe you need a `long` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'll try that out first. It seems that Hibernate mapping only works if all of the variables have the complementary data types to that of the objects in MS SQL table? Am I right along this line?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I still get the same error. How do I solve it?

Comment: I've managed to solve it. I used `String` for all of my variables and I managed to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what types you are exactly using here, but at least `DateTime` is not a standard type that is supported by Hibernate. If Hibernate does not know about a type, it tries to flush the value in its serialized form as blob/byte[]. If you would use `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.util.Calendar` or any other type that is supported by Hibernate out of the box, this should work properly.

Comment: Initially, I chose DateTime because the data type of my variables have to be matched with the data type of the object in MS SQL. But, upon realising the fact that it could not deserialise, I changed it to `String`.